# Regex isn't picking up my pattern properly

Tags: python, regex

## Context

I was doing the "Simple Symbols" CoderByte challenge and wanted to use regex because why not and now just simply want to not run into this in the future.

Here's the challenge straight from CoderByte:

Have the function SimpleSymbols(str) take the str parameter being passed and determine if it is an acceptable sequence by either returning the string true or false. The str parameter will be composed of + and = symbols with several letters between them (ie. ++d+===+c++==a) and for the string to be true each letter must be surrounded by a + symbol. So the string to the left would be false. The string will not be empty and will have at least one letter.

## Summary of the issue

My issue is that my regex pattern, `(?!\+)[a-zA-Z](?!\+)` is not picking up "==a+". What I think the pattern does is look for an alphabetical symbol that isn't surrounded by plus signs, however it doesn't find the "==a+" and I simply can't figure out why.

## Code

```py
import re

def SimpleSymbols(string):
    pat = r'(?!\+)[a-zA-Z](?!\+)'
    has_pat = re.search(pat, string) == None
    return has_pat

print(SimpleSymbols('+x==+x+').lower()) # False
print(SimpleSymbols('+x+==+x+')) # True
print(SimpleSymbols('x')) # False
print(SimpleSymbols('2+x+x+')) # True
print(SimpleSymbols('==a+')) # False, but wrongly returns True
```

## Solution

Many thanks to Wiktor Stribiżew who found the solution `\b[a-zA-Z]\b(?<!\+[a-zA-Z](?=\+))`. I don't know exactly why mine didn't work nor why this works, but I have a solution to the challenge.

monK_ also has a beautiful solution of `[^+][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][^+]` which is a bit more self explanatory. Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following pattern

```
[^+][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][^+]
```

If the pattern can be found, then the string does not follow the rules of the challenge.

Comment: Thanks for the solution!! I hope you don't mind if I ask what my original solution was actually doing. I'm new to regex and I want to avoid making the same mistake later.